# Is there a simple closed form of $|\alpha(\sqrt{n}-\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right \rfloor) + \beta(\sqrt{n}-\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right \rfloor)|$?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions, absolute-value, natural-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $d_n(x)$ denote the $n$'th digit after the decimal point in $x$. 
Examples:
$d_8(e) = 2,\;d_5(\pi) = 9$

$\alpha(x)$ and $\beta(x)$ are defined this way:

$$d_n(\alpha(x))  = \left\{
\begin{array}{c l}     
    0 & \;d_n(x)\leq5\\
    d_n(x)-5 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.$$

$$d_n(\beta(x))  = \left\{
\begin{array}{c l}     
    0 & \;d_n(x)\geq5\\
    5-d_n(x) & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.$$

Now consider$|\alpha(\sqrt{n}-\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right \rfloor) - \beta(\sqrt{n}-\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right \rfloor)|$, which yield numbers in the form of
$a\sqrt{b} - \frac{c}{9}$ or
$\frac{d}{9} - e \sqrt{f}$, where $a,b,c,d,e,f,n$ all are integers greater than $0$.

Or , in more detail: $$0<\sqrt{n}-\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right \rfloor < \frac{1}{2} \implies \sqrt{n}-\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right \rfloor = \frac{d}{9} - e \sqrt{f}$$

$$\frac{1}{2}<\sqrt{n}-\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right \rfloor \implies \sqrt{n}-\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right \rfloor = a\sqrt{b} - \frac{c}{9}$$

$$\sqrt{n}-\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right \rfloor = 0 \implies \sqrt{n}-\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right \rfloor = \frac{d}{9} - e \sqrt{n}$$

**The question:**

Does $|\alpha(\sqrt{n}-\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right \rfloor) + \beta(\sqrt{n}-\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right \rfloor)|$ have similary simple forms?

---

Please excuse any misuse of special characters, as my knowledge of what special characters usually denote is lacking. I simply used $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as I started out using $a$ and $b$ in their place.

Comment: It's purely conjecture from my side; but I haven't been able to disprove it yet, so until someone disproves it, I take it "as good fish".

Answer (score 5):

Just to make sure everything's formal and nice, we should probably  state somewhere that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have no digits to the left of the decimal point - we could extend them somehow, but for simplicity, let's just consider them maps $(0,1)\rightarrow(0,1)$ - so we're staying in the unit interval. Also, since some rationals do not have a unique decimal representation, we'll only work with irrational numbers.

The first thing to note is that, as I think you are trying to get at in your post, for any $x\in(0,1)$ the difference $\alpha(x)-\beta(x)=x-\frac{5}9$. This is fairly easy to prove - in particular, note that, if $S$ is the set of positions $n$ such that $d_n(x)<5$ and $S^{C}$ is the complement thereof, we get
$$\alpha(x)=\sum_{n\in S}10^{-n}(d_n(x)-5)$$
$$\beta(x)=\sum_{n\in S^C}10^{-n}(5-d_n(x))$$
which is just summing up the decimal expansion of each. This means that
$$\alpha(x)-\beta(x)=\left(\sum_{n\in S}10^{-n}(d_n(x)-5)\right)+\left(\sum_{n\in S^C}10^{-n}(d_n(x)-5)\right)$$
where we have negated the expression for $\beta$ by switching $(5-d_n(x))$ to $(d_n(x)-5)$. However, the same term is being summed in both sides, so really, we can take the same sum over $S\cup S^{C}=\mathbb{N}$ - this gives
$$\alpha(x)-\beta(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}10^{-n}(d_n(x)-5)$$
$$\alpha(x)-\beta(x)=\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}10^{-n}d_n(x)\right)-\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}5\cdot 10^{-n}\right)$$
where the sum on the left is clearly just $x$, being the decimal expansion therefore, and the sum on the right is a geometric series and converges to $\frac{5}9$, leaving
$$\alpha(x)-\beta(x)=x-\frac{5}9.$$

Notice that this applies to *every* $x$ - there's nothing special about the numbers $\sqrt{n}-\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$ that makes it easier to write your difference. If you can write $x$ easily, you can write $\alpha(x)-\beta(x)$ equally easily. (And obviously taking the absolute value hardly changes anything).

The expression $\alpha(x)+\beta(x)$, however, we would expect to be much harder to write out explicitly, except by computing it. In particular, notice that $\alpha(x)-\beta(x)$ is easy to write - meaning that, if $\alpha(x)+\beta(x)$ were easy to write, so must their difference, which is $2\beta(x)$. But it is somewhat absurd to think that $\beta(x)$ alone would have a nice closed form! It would require deep results about the digits of $x$ to create a closed form, and mathematics simply doesn't have the tools to say much about the digits of numbers even as simple as $\sqrt{n}$. We don't even know if its digits behave [somewhat randomly or not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number). Moreover, if every digit of $\sqrt{n}$ occurs infinitely often for any non-square $n$ - which is generally believed to be true - the value $\beta(\sqrt{n}-\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor)$, which has only digits $0$ through $5$ could not possibly be expressed as a square root of any other number plus a rational, implying that, since $\alpha+\beta$ would have no nice form.

Perhaps the only thing we can easily say is that, if we wrote $\alpha(x)-\beta(x)$ in base $10$, but using digits $-5$ through $4$ instead of the usual digits (meaning that the number $15$ would be represented, for instance, as the two digits $2,-5$ in this base system, since $2\cdot 10^1 + (-5)\cdot 10^0=15$. Check out [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary) on Wikipedia for a similar base system), then $\alpha(x)+\beta(x)$, in typical decimal, is just $\alpha(x)-\beta(x)$ in the modified decimal, where we ignore the negative signs in the digits. This is because, the digits from $-\beta(x)$ turn out to be $d_n(x)-5$, which are the digits $-5$ through $0$ and the digits from $\alpha(x)$ are those from $0$ to $4$ - so we're basically ensuring that we never have to carry. For instance, if
$$\alpha(x)-\beta(x)=.3572\ldots$$
then, in our modified decimal system, we would write it out as
$$\alpha(x)-\beta(x)=.4,-4,-3,2,\ldots$$
which would mean that $x$ is just those digits, plus $5$, so $x=.9127\ldots$.
(check it for yourself that $.3572 = 4\cdot 10^{-1}+(-4)\cdot 10^{-2}+(-3)\cdot 10^{-3}+2\cdot 10^{-4}$, if you doubt my weird-base-conversion-skills). Then, $\alpha(x)+\beta(x)$ is just the freaky decimal conversion without its signs, and is hence
$$\alpha(x)+\beta(x)=.4432\ldots$$
This gives, at the least, a procedure for obtaining $\alpha(x)+\beta(x)$ (and also for obtaining $x$) given knowledge of $\alpha(x)-\beta(x)$, but I doubt any better relations can be found.

If you have questions, I'd be happy to answer them; I can understand that my techniques may be confusing, since they are very much non-standard.

Comment: I really like that you are utilizing base conversion in this problem, as it was an approach I was looking into.
Thanks for your nice answer!
As soon as the grace period starts, ill award you the bounty, given there will be no other, more thorough answers! (Even though you answer is everything other than an  incomplete answer)!
Nice job! :)